# I dont press enter but ReadLine() says I did (accidently made it that you cant answer the old one so repost)

Tags: c#

Fixed, but now it automatically presses enter when it gets to the `Main();` thing and I can't actually input anything in time. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Bruh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int pog = 0;
            int pog2 = 0;
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Input a whole number");
            string poggers = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(poggers, out pog))
            {
                pog = int.Parse(poggers);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number higher than the previous");
            string poggers2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(poggers2, out pog2))
            {
                pog2 = int.Parse(poggers2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            int genRand = r.Next(pog, pog2);
            Console.WriteLine("This number was randomly generated between " + pog + " and " + pog2 + " and we got: " + genRand);
            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
            ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey();
            if (answer.KeyChar == 'y' || answer.KeyChar == 'Y')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Main();
            }
            else if (answer.KeyChar == 'n' || answer.KeyChar == 'N')
            {
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Y/N not any other character");
                Console.Read();
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I'm sorry if this breaks any rules or anything but I'm very new to this site and dont understand it very well :(

Comment: Please give your variables names so that people are able to understand what you're trying to do. Also naming your variables like that won't get you very far in creatings some more complex things.
Which line exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: @Dominik sorry I'm not very good at coding. I don't really know where it occurs, but it happens near the end I assume because if I get rid of the `ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey();` and all the if statements and such that follow afterwards only leaving `Main();` left, it works perfectly fine. Edit: Wait no it doesn't thats weird it was working before.

Comment: Hey Dude, please take a look at the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if possible, [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem. (this is my default copy&paste, please read it, it will help you getting answers :)  )

Comment: Also, if you struggle debugging your code, i'd suggest reading about this topic. It really helps understanding 'whats happening'. [Here is an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) but there are plenty good guides available.

Comment: Also ... ;)
You should not call `Main` inside your `Main`. Try writing methods for your different cases, i.e.: `void GenerateRandomNumberBetween(int from, int to)`, `bool ValidateUserInput(string input)`, `int GetNumberInput()` ... etc. Those are examples, you'll need to adapt. Don't put anything in one method. Write small methods, that are re-usable.

Comment: @nilsK thanks ill check the article and how to ask page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked your code into something that is more C#-like :-) - find this below.

Highlights:

- You use `int.TryParse()` correctly, but do the conversion again
  inside the **true** code block, using `int.Parse()`.
- No need to call `System.Environment.Exit(1);` to terminate the program, just let it end.
- The call `main()` is actually a recursive call - where a method (function) calls it self. Usable sometimes, but i often leads to a *StackOverflow* exception. In this case, you get some strange behaviour...

```
using System;

namespace Bruh2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            bool tryAgain = true;

            while (tryAgain)
            {
                int pog = 0;
                int pog2 = 0;
                Random r = new Random();

                Console.Write("Input a whole number: ");
                string poggers = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!int.TryParse(poggers, out pog))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                    poggers = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.Write("Input a number higher than the previous: ");
                string poggers2 = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!int.TryParse(poggers2, out pog2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Not a number. Please input a number and not letters.");
                    poggers2 = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                int genRand = r.Next(pog, pog2);
                Console.WriteLine("This number was randomly generated between " + pog + " and " + pog2 + " and we got: " + genRand);
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
                //ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey();
                string answer = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString().ToLower();
                while (answer!="y" && answer!="n")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Y/N not any other character");
                    answer = Console.ReadKey().ToString().ToLower();
                }
                if (answer == "n")
                {
                    tryAgain = false; // terminate the loop (and thereby the program)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!